# Spring security oauth2 server - intercept unauthorized denied access

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, cloud, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I'd like to intercept below access denied response from a spring cloud oauth2 authorisation server:

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

I'like to intercept the exception and do some custom redirection or display custom page.

Any hints on how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by extending **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter** and override **configure(http)** method with this additional code:

```
...
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());
...

@Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {

        return (request, response, authException) -> {
            LOGGER.info("\n!!!!!!!! unauthorized: {} !!!!!!!!!!!!", authException.getMessage());
            String uri = request.getContextPath() + "/login";
            if(loadBalancerClient!=null && loadBalancerClient.choose("API-GATEWAY") != null) {
                uri = loadBalancerClient.choose("API-GATEWAY").getUri().toString();
            }
            response.sendRedirect(uri);
        };
    }
```